# PaginatorHelper includes routing prefixes when default routes are disabled

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, pagination

I have disabled CakePHP default routes and have added some of my own. I have first create a routing prefix:

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('settings));
```

And then I have added some routes:

```
Router::connect('/users', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index', 'settings' => true));
Router::connect('/users/add', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add', 'settings' => true));
Router::connect('/users/:id', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view', 'settings' => true), array('pass' => array('id'), 'id' => '[0-9]+'));
Router::connect('/users/:id/edit', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'edit', 'settings' => true), array('pass' => array('id'), 'id' => '[0-9]+'));
Router::connect('/users/:id/delete', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'delete', 'settings' => true), array('pass' => array('id'), 'id' => '[0-9]+'));
```

Building links with `Html::link` method works quite right:

```
$this->Html->link('Users', '/users')
```

generates

```
'/users'
```

and the action within `UsersController` is `settings_index` as expected.

However, `PaginatorHelper::sort` prepends `/settings`, like this:

```
'/settings/users/index/sort:username/direction:asc'
```

which actually only works if I enable the built-in routes. So I have two questions:

1. How can I make `PaginatorHelper` not to prepend `'/settings'`?
2. How can I make the PaginatorHelper named parameters work with my custom routes, so that I can have URL like `'/users/sort:email/direction:desc'`?

Thanks!!

Comment: What happens when you try to generate a link using Router::url()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem actually involves two things since default routes are disabled.

First I have to provide named parameters for `PaginationHelper`:

```
Router::connectNamed(array(
  'sort' => array('action' => 'index', 'controller' => array('users')),
  'direction' => array('action' => 'index', 'controller' => array('users')),
));
```

And then I have to provide routes for controllers and actions using pagination:

```
Router::connect('/users/index/*', array(
  'controller' => 'users',
  'action' => 'index',
  'settings' => true
));
```

It is important to say that this route should be at the end of the routes starting with `'/users'`. Otherwise the asterisk will take precedence. So my final set of routes looks like this:

```
Router::connectNamed(array(
  'sort' => array('action' => 'index', 'controller' => array('users')),
  'direction' => array('action' => 'index', 'controller' => array('users')),
));

Router::connect('/users', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index', 'settings' => true));
Router::connect('/users/add', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add', 'settings' => true));
Router::connect('/users/:id', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view', 'settings' => true), array('pass' => array('id'), 'id' => '[0-9]+'));
Router::connect('/users/:id/edit', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'edit', 'settings' => true), array('pass' => array('id'), 'id' => '[0-9]+'));
Router::connect('/users/:id/delete', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'delete', 'settings' => true), array('pass' => array('id'), 'id' => '[0-9]+'));

Router::connect('/users/index/*', array(
  'controller' => 'users',
  'action' => 'index',
  'settings' => true
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command before your sort functions:

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('url' => array_merge(array('settings' => false), $this->passedArgs)));
```

This essentially sets some defaults for the paginator helper to use before it runs those functions. By setting `settings` to `false`, you will tell it not to set that route.